# How to check if process started with ShellExecute is launched?

Tags: c#

I'm writing a program to open several links and paths in new windows and put them to certain spots on a certain screen.

Until now I use the code below:

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("shell32.dll", EntryPoint = "ShellExecute")]
    public static extern long ShellExecute(int hwnd, string cmd, string file, string param1, string param2, int swmode);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowPos")]
    public static extern IntPtr SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, int hWndInsertAfter, int x, int Y, int cx, int cy, int wFlags);


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntPtr hwnd;

        ShellExecute(0, "open", "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe", "www.example.de", "", 5);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, 0, 0, 960, 1080, 0);

        //and so on for 8 applications on 4 screens...
    }
}
```

I used the ugly sleep command because it takes some time for this old Computer to open the URL or application.

Is there a way to check if the window is open yet? 
So the program only proceeds when the Window is already there.

Comment: Do use the Process class, its WaitForInputIdle() method is a pretty reliable way to ensure it had enough time to create its main window, beats Thread.Sleep() any time.  You'll probably like its MainWindowHandle property as well.  But do be aware of the process not behaving quite as you like, specific to FireFox is that it might update itself when you start it up.  This just can't be 100% reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look into setting commandline switches of the specific browser and skip the P/Invoke. Here is an example for Google Chrome:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    OpenUrl("www.example.com")
        .ContinueWith((lastTask) =>
            OpenUrl("www.example.de")
        ).ContinueWith((lastTask) =>
            OpenUrl("www.google.com")
        ).ContinueWith((lastTask) =>
            OpenUrl("www.stackoverflow.com")
        ).Wait();
}

private static Task OpenUrl(string url)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var chromePath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";

        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(chromePath, $"--user-data-dir=a --window-position=2400,400 --window-size=500,500 --app=\"http://{url}\"");
        var process = Process.Start(startInfo);

        process.WaitForInputIdle();
    });
}
```

Where we set the window-position and window-size as an argument to the ProcessStartInfo.